# How to fix my code to show alert dialog on flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an app which exports a json object to a json file and while it's exporting, I wanted to show an alert dialog with a circular progress indicator on it. But for some reason, the alert dialog with my progress indicator is not showing up.

This is the look of my app before I export my json:

[image]

Here is the code for activating the exporting part:

```
...

child: FlatButton(
  onPressed: () async{
    //Popping the confirm dialog
    Navigator.pop(context);
    //Showing the progress dialog
    showProcessingDialog();
    //Buying some time
    _timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), exportData);
    //Pops the progress dialog
    Navigator.pop(context);
    //Shows the finished dialog
    showFinishedDialog();
    },
  child: Text(
    "Yes",
```

...

After I click 'Yes' in this alert button, it should show the progress dialog but it doesn't show, instead it shows the finished dialog.

Like this:

[image]

Here is the code for progress dialog:

```
void showProcessingDialog() async{
return showDialog(

  barrierDismissible: false,
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context){

    return AlertDialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      content: Container(
        width: 250.0,
        height: 100.0,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            CircularProgressIndicator(),
            Text("Exporting...",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "OpenSans",
                color:  Color(0xFF5B6978)
                )
              )
          ]
          )
        )


      );
  }
  );
}
```

Here is the exportData callback:

```
void exportData() async{
  List<dynamic> _msgList = await _msgStorage._getList;
  await _expData._saveList(_msgList);
}
```

I have tried to add Timer class to delay showing finished dialog for 3 seconds but it doesn't work. I can confirm that my json file was exported successfully but the callback of Timer which is the progress dialog didn't show up.

I would appreciate any kind of help.

**UPDATE**:

I rewrote my code based on the answer of diegoveloper:

```
onPressed: () async{

  Navigator.pop(context);
  print("confirm dialog has pop");

  print("showing processdialog");
  showProcessingDialog();
  print("processdialog is being shown.");

  print("buying some time");
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
  print("done buying some time");

  print("exporting begin");
  await exportData();
  print("exporting done");

  Navigator.pop(context);
  print("processdialog has pop");

  print("showing finished dialog");
  showFinishedDialog();
  print("finished dialog is being shown.");
},
```

At this point, the process dialog is being shown but after printing the "exporting done" and executing the `Navigator.pop(context);` it gave an error and the process dialog remains in the screen, unpopped.

Like this:

[image]

```
I/flutter ( 9767): confirm dialog has pop
I/flutter ( 9767): showing processdialog
I/flutter ( 9767): processdialog is being shown.
I/flutter ( 9767): buying some time
I/flutter ( 9767): done buying some time
I/flutter ( 9767): exporting begin
I/flutter ( 9767): exporting done
E/flutter ( 9767): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 9767): Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
E/flutter ( 9767): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable. To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling inheritFromWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
```

After I comment out the `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));` it worked fine.

My question is why did it failed when using `Future.delayed`?

Here is the full error:

```
I/flutter ( 9767): confirm dialog has pop
I/flutter ( 9767): showing processingdialog
I/flutter ( 9767): processdialog is being shown.
I/flutter ( 9767): buying some time
I/flutter ( 9767): done buying some time
I/flutter ( 9767): exporting begin
I/flutter ( 9767): exporting done
E/flutter ( 9767): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 9767): Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
E/flutter ( 9767): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable. To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling inheritFromWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
E/flutter ( 9767): 
E/flutter ( 9767): #0      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3246:9)
E/flutter ( 9767): #1      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3255:6)
E/flutter ( 9767): #2      Element.ancestorStateOfType (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3303:12)
E/flutter ( 9767): #3      Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1288:19)
E/flutter ( 9767): #4      ChatWindow.showExportedDialog.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:msgdiary/main.dart:368:37)
E/flutter ( 9767): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9767): #5      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:507:14)
E/flutter ( 9767): #6      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:562:30)
E/flutter ( 9767): #7      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
E/flutter ( 9767): #8      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:9)
E/flutter ( 9767): #9      TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:175:7)
E/flutter ( 9767): #10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:315:9)
E/flutter ( 9767): #11     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:73:12)
E/flutter ( 9767): #12     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:11)
E/flutter ( 9767): #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:180:19)
E/flutter ( 9767): #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:22)
E/flutter ( 9767): #15     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:138:7)
E/flutter ( 9767): #16     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
E/flutter ( 9767): #17     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:85:7)
E/flutter ( 9767): #18     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:168:13)
E/flutter ( 9767): #19     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:122:5)
```

**UPDATE**:

It was my fault. I need to study more about context. It seems that I was popping the same context for the two dialogs. I changed the name of the dialog and it worked.

Comment: You should replace the widget within your dialog for a progress bar/circle and update it back again when the work is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
    onPressed: () async{
        //Popping the confirm dialog
        Navigator.pop(context);
        //Showing the progress dialog
        showProcessingDialog();
        //wait 5 seconds : just for testing purposes, you don't need to wait in a real scenario
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
        //call export data
        await exportData();
        //Pops the progress dialog
        Navigator.pop(context);
        //Shows the finished dialog
        await showFinishedDialog();
        },
```

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestion and it showed the process dialog. However, there is a tiny error. I updated the post for that. Thanks.

Comment: Don't mind my first comment. It was my fault for using the same name for the contexts.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you extract it to a custom dialog widget and handle its states dynamically? It's cleaner and more customizable, also giving a timer (like you did of 5 seconds) it's not a good practice since you can't be sure how much time it will take to do its work.

[image]

Then I can suggest, for example, to create an `enum DialogState` with 3 states

```
enum DialogState {
  LOADING,
  COMPLETED,
  DISMISSED,
}
```

Then create your own Dialog widget that when built receives its current state

```
class MyDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  final DialogState state;
  MyDialog({this.state});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return state == DialogState.DISMISSED
        ? Container()
        : AlertDialog(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(10.0),
              ),
            ),
            content: Container(
              width: 250.0,
              height: 100.0,
              child: state == DialogState.LOADING
                  ? Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                          child: Text(
                            "Exporting...",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "OpenSans",
                              color: Color(0xFF5B6978),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  : Center(
                      child: Text('Data loaded with success'),
                    ),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

and then, in your screen, you can insert it anywhere you want. I changed my `exportData` function to dummy a request that takes 5 seconds.

```
class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyScreenState createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  DialogState _dialogState = DialogState.DISMISSED;

  void _exportData() {
    setState(() => _dialogState = DialogState.LOADING);
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)).then((_) {
      setState(() => _dialogState = DialogState.COMPLETED);
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () => setState(() => _dialogState = DialogState.DISMISSED));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Show dialog'),
              onPressed: () => _exportData(),
            ),
            MyDialog(
              state: _dialogState,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, I'm worried if I call the setState method, it would rebuild my widget tree. I have a streambuilder widget which listens and displays the list of messages onto my Screen State.

Comment: You can also do this with stream builders an listen to changes on your dialog. When you want to update the message you just need to add to your stream the news state. Also, remember that `setState` will only rebuild the widgets that contains changes.